# Get fragment's navigation drawer from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have MainActivity which is holding 2 fragments. First fragment has navigation drawer, the second fragment not. In the MainActivity i want to override onBackPressed() method so when the navigation drawer is opened, it has to close the fragment. But i don't know how to get fragment's navigation drawer's state from Activity. Here's the code :

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

**FragmentListProduct.java**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_product_layout, container, false);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) mainView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    fragmentActivity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) mainView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(fragmentActivity, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    drawerToggle.syncState();

    navigationView = (NavigationView) mainView.findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_cat_all);
}
```

Of course it gives me error `Cannot resolve symbol darwerlayout`.
Before i made `drawerLayout` as a static field, but i got warning `Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)`. So how to solve this problem, or maybe you have another solution :D

Comment: I think you have this all wrong. Why would you want to have a drawer inside a fragment? If you want your drawer to have a fragment you should put the fragment inside the drawer and then move the drawer layout logic to MainActivity. But in your case you can use `findFragmentById` to find the fragment and use a public method in the fragment to do this.

Comment: @NaveenDissanayake I don't think that this going wrong way. its based on his requirement. and way that he present its proper. for me its new leavening curve

Comment: what do you mean with "drawer have a fragment?", "fragment inside the drawer"..
What i know, drawer is containing menu, not fragment.. sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the fragment using the tag, which you'll have to assign when invoking the fragment, like this:

```
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "the_tag_here")
    .commit();
```

Access it using `getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("the_tag")`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    FragmentListProduct fragment =  (FragmentListProduct) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("the_tag_here");

    if (fragment != null) {
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout = fragment.drawerLayout;
       //make drawerLayout public in the fragment
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }

    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Comment: what is drawerLayout in line of  DrawerLayout drawerLayout = fragment.drawerLayout;

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

1. Put your navigation drawer in your main activity.
2. open the second fragment in the new activity if you do not want navigation drawer there.

Solution 2:

1. Create a method in your fragment say checkNavigationDrawer().
2. Get a fragment reference in your activity like this

   ```
   Fragment yourFragment = (YourFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.containerId);
   ```
3. In your onBackPressed () call yourFragment.checkNavigationDrawer(); like this

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed() {
       yourFragment.checkNavigationDrawer();
       super.onBackPressed();
   }
   ```
4. In your checkNavigationDrawer method check if the navigation drawer is open or not if it is open close it.

   ```
   public void checkNavigationDrawer(){
         if(drawerLayout.isOpen()){
             drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
         }

   }
   ```

Comment: Can you give me the code of isDrawerOpen()? because if i create it, I need to make the drawerLayout as static field which will gives me warning leak memory

Comment: there is no need to make drawer layout static .i'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

- Hold your `FragmentListProduct` object in your `MainActivity`.
- Create one method called `isDrawerOpen()` in the `FragmentListProduct` fragment.
- Now you can call the `isDrawerOpen()` from `MainActivity` by using the `FragmentListProduct` class object.

Go for it!

Comment: Can you give me the code of `isDrawerOpen()`? because if i create it, I need to  make the drawerLayout as static field which will gives me warning `leak memory`